# Is it practical to store my customer root CA certificate in browser session store for my we app?

Tags: web-applications, certificate, progressive-web-apps, digital-signature, x509certificate

I have a desktop based application that has a hard coded root CA. My application can obtain digitally signed resources and verify these with the supplied certificates, and uses the Root CA stored in the app.

Now, I am moving my desktop app to an online based web application.

I can not store my Root CA in the offline trust store (not practice to get users to manually install).

So I am thinking, as my web application and back end server use TLS, once the initial HTTPS handshake is complete, would it be possible for my web app to download my Root CA from my server and store it in the local storage of the browser, so that it can be used to validate digital certificates?

Just to be clear, I am NOT referring to client app/server authentication, this is taken care of using standard HTTPS/TSL and a CA signed server certificate.

I am referring to the custom functionality of my app. Logged in users create resources and sign them, with are then sent to the back end server, and can be downloaded by other users of the web app, who need to be able to check the signature of the resources.

I hope that makes sense and any advice would be great.

Thank you

Edit

It may help if I describe the application scenario.

So a Doctor logs into the web app with username and password and my back end server authenticates the user. He then compiled a prescription in the web app and signs it with his private key (obtained from a cloud HCM) and the signed prescription is uploaded and validated then stored in my back end database.

Now, a pharmacist logs into their front end web app and downloads the prescription. At this point in my desktop version the signature is validated by building a chain of trust with a hard coded root CA in the desktop app. But as I wish to love this to a web app I can’t do that. So I was thinking is it ok for my web app to download the root CA as it’s now secure over HTTPS?

I am also thinking that as this would now be an online web app, and the connection is over HTTPS, is this even necessary because when the Dr signs and uploads the prescription document my server code validated it. Then as the pharmacist downloads it from my server app over SSL it’s already trusted? Is it any more secure or necessary (or acceptable) to download the root CA?

Just to clarify. The root CA in this instance is a self signed CA certificate that I can’t add to the OS offline trusted store. When my app was a desktop based app this was not a problem. My app trusted this certificate as it was hard coded.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks again

Comment: How is the online version of the application going to work? Do you have Javascript to retrieve the CA certificate from local storage and use it to validate a chain of trust? (sounds difficult)

Comment: Thanks for reply. User login into online web application and authenticates to back end Node JS server. Its actually a pretty straight forward app but the offline desktop version has Root CA coded into the app. I thought once initial web app to server SSL/TLS has taken place I could securely temporarily download a root certificate and verify resource/document signatures in the web app? Thanks

Comment: What piece of software exactly will securely temporarily download a root certificate and verify resource/document signatures?

Answer (score 0):

Root or any Certificates are public and may not need to be protected using SSL/TLS, as discussed in some of the comments.

Having said that, since it's a web application, users can trust validation of signed content done by the server.

If you want to validate it on client, you may cache the root certificate on the client browser. You may even use localStorage for long term caching on the browser.

Comment: Thank you, however, the content is not signed by the server. It’s signed by a user logged into the app, then uploaded to a backend database where other users can download into their browser using the web app. I need them to be able to verify the signature

Comment: What I mean is server can verify signature (using public key of source user) and then would serve content along with verified flag to **other users**. If client user needs to verify signature, they need to have public key (or say certificate) of all source users.

Comment: Ok I see. So it would be secure enough to allow an end user to sign and upload content to my back end. Then when another user requests the signed data from the back end, the back end server validated the signature and sends the data as valued over SSL to the end user and they are safe to trust the signature is valid? If this is acceptable it would certainly make developing easier.

Comment: Should be acceptable if your web application meets all the security requirements..!! Check if there is any guidance from any enforcing authority or law of land..!

Answer (score 0):

> > But as I wish to love this to a web app I can’t do that. So I was thinking is it ok for my web app to download the root CA as it’s now secure over HTTPS?

I sense a confusion here. To be clear, The HTTPS/TLS session starts Only after the client has validated the certificate presented by the server. It is important to understand the TLS handshake process here, The TLS handshake process contains two important steps which are

1. Client-Hello
2. Server-Hello

During Server-Hello step the server presents it's certificate to the client, client accepts the certificate only after  validity check of the certificate is PASSED, One of the validity check is,

> **Whether the certificate is issued by an known certificate authority ( Root**
> **CA/Intermediate CA)**

Only after validity check pass the HTTPS/TLS sessions becomes active, before this, the entire communication happens in TCP but not TLS/HTTPS.

There are several ways you could solve your problem, some I could think of is,

1. Obtain your server certificate from a recognized certificate authority (Recommended)
2. Provide a manual to end-users to accept the self-signed certificate as trusted

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am not confusing this its just difficult to explain my use case. In fact I have an EV SSL to connect to the app at HTTPS://app.myapp.com so that's not the issue. Its after this that my users sign and verify content, however, I think the last comment below should help as that's what I was hoping. It was no issue with Desktop apps but different when using server/client. Thanks again

Comment: May i know your certificate hierarchy ? ( Root --> Intermediate1 --> Intermediate2 --> Leaf ? ) ? Is there a possibility that you could use the [ https ] root certificate for prescription purposes as well ? In this case it is already available in your browser !

Comment: Sure. The website EV ask is standard. 

My PKI is Root cert - Sub CA - client cert. 

Thanks